# ggridges: alturas dos picos proporcionais às quantidades

Tags: r, ggplot2

Alguém saberia se é possível, usando o `ggridges`, fazer as alturas proporcionais às quantidades?

Segue o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que a altura do cume do primeiro elemento, A624, com valor 5.504, aparenta ser a mesma do último elemento, A674, com valor 21. Teria como fazer esses cumes proporcionais a esses valores em no eixo y?

Segue o código utilizado

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(dplyr)

    dt <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ronycoelho/databases/master/data_councils.csv")
    
    # Count each element
    councils_qt <- dt %>% 
      count(councils) %>% 
      arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
      mutate (councils_qt = paste0(councils, " (", n, ")"))
    
    # Join to make labels
    dt <- dt %>% 
      full_join(councils_qt)
    
    ggplot(dt, aes(x=years, 
                   y=reorder(councils_qt, -years, FUN = mean)))+
        geom_density_ridges()
```

Já tentei colocar o y como `numeric` e usar o argumento `height`. Esse argumento até transforma o dado proporcionalmente, mas desconfigura os cumes.

```
    ggplot(dt, aes(x=years, 
                   y=reorder(n, -years, FUN = mean),
                   height = n ))+
        geom_density_ridges()
```

Alguém sugeriria alguma saída?

Comment: O `ggridges` retorna a [densidade](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html), se desejado obter alturas com diferentes escalas, sugiro utilizar gráfico de barra ou área.

Answer (score 0):

Vcoê consegue fazer isso usando `height = ..count..` e `geom_density_ridges(stat = "density")`

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=years, 
               y=reorder(councils_qt, -years, FUN = mean),
               height = ..count..)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "density")
```